# Creating new Date Time from string

Tags: php

I have a string which is '23/05/2013' and I wanted to create a new Date Time object from this, so I did:

```
new \DateTime('23/05/2013');
```

Any idea why I am getting this error all the time:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (23/05/2013) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

Comment: Use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` so you can specify the format.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-create.php If you are getting an error like this:

Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (13/02/2013) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character in DateTime->__construct()

Note that when you create a new date object using a format with slashes and dashes  it must be in the mm/dd/yy(yy) Months always before years (the american style) otherwise you'll get an incorrect date and may get an error like the one above (where PHP is crashing on trying to decode a 13th month).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

It's mm/dd/yyyy, which is American, not British

Use

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/05/2013');
```

Answer (score 41):

If you want to use the object normally rather than statically try this:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$newDate = $datetime->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/05/2013');
```

then you can use it like normal:

```
echo $newDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: This one will return current date, instead the one provided in createFromFormat function.
It should be `$newDate = $datetime->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/05/2013');`
As 'createFromFormat' returns DateTime object.

Comment: `createFromFormat` is a static method.  Actually it's a **factory method design pattern** so it should be used like : `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/05/2013');`