# validating date field for if the user picks a past date

Tags: php, html

before I post this, i want to clarify I have checked the previous threads and im aware that they have past solutions for this particular question. However, upon implementing my own version, I kept getting errors so was wondering if there was a better style suited for my situation.

heres my code:

php:

```
$startDate=$_POST['startDate'];
$newDate = date("dd-mm-yyyy", strtotime($startDate));
$now = new DateTime();

if ($newDate< $now) {

    $dateErr = "*Please ensure you select a valid date";
}
```

html (this is a piece from the actual form):

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="startDate"> Start Date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="date" name="startDate">
        <span class="error"> <?php 
        if (isset($dateErr)) {
        echo $dateErr;
        } 
        ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I even tried to apply this type of example from one of the threads: https://eval.in/private/422a20b3661d4b

but it kept giving me some sort of trace error like it couldn't recognise the date?

Comment: the question's unclear in regards to what the `$now` variable is, the missing form and what's being passed through the POST array.

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that, changed. nothing comes up when i use print_r

Comment: Try `if($newDate->diff($now)->format("%r") == "-")`

Comment: seeing the edit; you're not using the right method here for `new DateTime()` and it requires it to be formatted properly https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php --- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757728/creating-new-date-time-from-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare value of same type and `$now` seems to be undefined.

Try something like this :

```
$startDate = $_POST['startDate'] ;
$newDate = strtotime($startDate) ;

if ($newDate < time()) {

    $dateErr = "*Please ensure you select a valid date";
}
```

Comment: I did a test with the value: 15/12/2017, print_r gave me this: 1513292400. not sure if that means it works?

Comment: That's a timestamp @JamesGreen

Comment: it seems to be still adding the date, do i need to add a ``return false`` statement to it? just so it returns the error and doesnt do anything else

Comment: @JamesGreen The `return` could be OK if your `if` is in a function.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean in ....... and so on