# Is there any inbuild function to convert different language date into common date format in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have an array of dates like

```
$arrDate = array('12-ápr.-2018', '8-anp.-2018', '11-Apr-2018', '03-mai-2018');
```

Can't say what all language dates are inside the array.

I have to convert the array into common format (like d-m-Y):

```
$arrDate = array('12-04-2018', '8-04-2018', '11-04-2018', '03-05-2018');
```

What i have tried:

**Try 1**: To convert the date to Unix timestamp using `strtotime()` but the result for other language date was empty string.

**Try 2**: To convert into timestamp using the `Date` class functions. But showing the error

> Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (16-ápr.-2018) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character

Please help me to with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757728/creating-new-date-time-from-string

Comment: @deadman :  `createFromFormat` will not work because format is not fixed

Comment: _“Can't say what all language dates are inside the array.”_ - well then how do you expect that to work in the first place? Any solution to this would need to know all possible ways of writing “April” there are upfront, if you want to be able to replace this with a month number “4”.

Comment: @CBore it is not only for April there may be any month.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` like below

```
  $arrDates = array('12-ápr.-2018', '8-anp.2018', '11-Apr-2018');
  foreach($arrDates as &$d){
    $d = str_replace(['ápr.-','anp.','Apr-'],'4-',$d);
  }
  print_r($arrDates);
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1035310)

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12-4-2018
    [1] => 8-4-2018
    [2] => 11-4-2018
)
```

Comment: the month is not always april, and i dont cant say what all languages are there in the array.

Comment: can you change your db structure and code to make right date format ?

Comment: Its already inserted old data for so long, so i cant do anything with the db structure.

Comment: Then like I did for month `4` you need to do for all month, and update in your database and then use proper date format on updated date format

Comment: Its hard to resolve `Can't say what all language dates are inside`

Comment: Thanks for your time let me check.

Comment: Your welcome, I hope you didn't down voted my answer here.